# Getting 401 response from C2DM

Tags: android

I am getting exception from google saying:

```
java.io.IOException: Received authentication challenge is null
```

I read that this is reproducing 401 error. So this

```
Indicates that the ClientLogin AUTH_TOKEN used to validate the sender is invalid.
```

But i have everything registreted and logined with ClientLogin successfully.
So what wrong could be?

Also do i need to reigstrate my app here ?

[Sing up for C2DM](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/signup?hl)

Because i haven't
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have u register your app on the given link . Also you should get mail from C2DM on mail id which you have mention in Contact email address.

Comment: Nope, so i need to make registration on that link ? so this isn't the same ?
            Intent registrationIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
            registrationIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
            registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", email);
            this.startService(registrationIntent);

Comment: you have to register at https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/signup?hl fill all information after that you will get mail as mention above. after that registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", email); put same email address here which you have mention in contact information